# Adding list of Indexes in wordpress document

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, table, documentation, noindex

I have been exploring wordpress to use it for documentation puposes. I'm stuck at a point where I am unable to add a list of Indexes to the document. 
Can I add indexes to a wordpress document the way indexes are added at the end of a  Microsoft Word Document?
Please help

Comment: Do you mean *table of contents* ? Not natively, afaik. There exists plugins for that , but plugin recommendations are off-topic here on [wordpress.se].

Comment: No I mean Indexes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(publishing)